# Maximum of Brownian Motion with drift

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian Motion. For $\mu>0$,  $$\max_{0\le t\le T}(B_t+\mu t)\neq\max_{0\le t\le T}B_t+\mu T.$$ Why is this not equal in general? Is this because $B_t+\mu t$ is not a martingale?

Comment: Not equal because for any objects $X$, $Y$, $max(X + Y) \not = max(X) + max(Y)$. However, inequality holds.